# Illegal configuration in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to build my project in Xcode, but I get the error message: "Illegal Configuration Launch screens may not have connections"

How can I resolve this? What does this mean?

[image: mac]

I have tried to remove the value from Launch Screen File, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @raurora: Thank you. How do I go to my target and remove the value from the "Launch Screen File" field?

Comment: I have now removed the value from Launch Screen File, but I still get the same error..

Comment: Have a look at this answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544288/illegal-configuration-in-xcode-6-0